# Webpage parsing in C# .Net with AngleSharp Results in Null

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, html-parsing, anglesharp

I'm trying to scrape some pages on walmart.com using AngleSharp, but for some reason it won't work. I've been using AngleSharp to scrape many sites in the past with no issue, but here it just won't do.

For simplicity, here's one page: https://www.walmart.com/ip/50908276, I'm trying to get the price of the item (currently at $9.99). In Chrome's Console when I type `document.getElementsByClassName("Price-characteristic")` I get a list of 60 `[span.Price-characteristic]` results. Perfect. But when I try the same using AngleBrackets it returns none.

Here's my code:

```
using AngleSharp;
using AngleSharp.Dom;

public async void GetPrice()
{
    var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
    string address = "https://www.walmart.com/ip/50908276";

    IDocument document = await
    BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(address);

    var priceDollar = document.GetElementsByClassName("Price-characteristic");
}
```

I'm not too familiar with HTML so I apologize for any stark ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

Using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and XPath

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
    var html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.walmart.com/ip/50908276");
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var price = doc.DocumentNode
                    .SelectSingleNode("//*[@data-product-price]")
                    .Attributes["data-product-price"]
                    .Value;

}
```

This code returns *price* as *9.99*

Comment: That gives me a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @SamWhite No, I just tried it now and it returns 9.99

Comment: That's odd. Try as I might, it just doesn't work by me. Please mind my ignorance, but where did you pick up the "data-product-price"? I can't seem to find it anywhere in the source or in Inspect.